# cant free up memory by creating and unseting object in for loop

Tags: php, memory-leaks

Im running a loop which creates an object (where some arrays get created) and unseting it afterwards right in the loop:

```
private function _runLoop($amountPerStep = 4){
    $steps = floor(count($this->_symbolRows)/$amountPerStep);
    $echo = "";
    for($i = 0; $i <= $steps; $i++){
        $tempSymbolRows = array_slice($this->_symbolRows,$i*$amountPerStep,($i+1)*$amountPerStep);
        if (count($tempSymbolRows) == 0) continue;
        $tempSymbols    = array();
        for($j = 0; $j < count($tempSymbolRows); $j++){
            $tempSymbols[] = $tempSymbolRows[$j][0];
        }
        $scrapping = new Scraping($tempSymbols);
        $echo .= "<pre>";
        $echo .= "memory_peak_usage / memory_usage <br/>";
        $echo .= memory_get_peak_usage()/1000000 ." / ". memory_get_usage() / 1000000 ."<br/><br/>";
        //print_r($scrapping->getArrays());
        $echo .= "</pre>";
        $scrapping = NULL;
        unset($scrapping);
        gc_collect_cycles();
        if( $i >= 3 ) break;
    }
    echo $echo;
}
```

after the third running in the lop im breaking the loop (testing purposes). i commented out the line where i print the arrays of the loop because it would eat up memory by saving the arrays for the print (even the object is not existing). thought that would be the problem. but when i run the loop i get this output

```
memory_peak_usage / memory_usage 
7.805928 / 1.530504

memory_peak_usage / memory_usage 
9.723464 / 6.28792

memory_peak_usage / memory_usage 
39.414088 / 17.227368

memory_peak_usage / memory_usage 
55.541584 / 23.166608
```

so the used memory size is getting bigger and bigger ...
where is the mistake ? 
why does the gc not freeing up ressources ?

Comment: the scrapping class is really big. but it does nothing moren than saving 20 arrays in another one.

Comment: Isn't `$tempSymbolRows` getting bigger in each loop?

Comment: $tempSymbolRows = array_slice($this->_symbolRows,$i*$amountPerStep,($i+1)*$amountPerStep);

Comment: nope. im overriding it. and this array will never eat up that much memory....

Comment: The length of `$tempSymbolRows` is increasing because `($i+1)*$amountPerStep` increases each step.

Comment: the array is getting created by slicing a part of another. my slicing interval is moving right each loop. yes ($i+1)*$amountPerStep is getting increaed but the start of the interval $i*$amountPerStep is also getting increaed the same amount. so the array shouldnt get bgger each row. but make sure im running it again.

Comment: of course putting out the size of the array each time

Comment: The third argument of array_splice is a `length` not an index.

Comment: Jim you got damn right. thank you. my prints also showed me that the size is increasing. you saved me. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the discussion in the comments.

```
$tempSymbolRows = array_slice($this->_symbolRows,$i*$amountPerStep,($i+1)*$amountPerStep);
```

This line creates a larger array each loop since the third argument to array_splice is not an offset. This causes an increase in memory use.